# Where can I find a list of azure identity scopes and their permission levels?

Tags: azure, scope, azure-managed-identity

**When...**

- creating a new service principal using something like `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n 'test' --sdk-auth`

...**then**...

- listing the new service principal attributes using `!az role assignment list --assignee 'serv_princ_obj_id'`

```
[
  {
    "canDelegate": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/redact/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/redact",
    "name": "redact",
    "principalId": "redact",
    "principalName": "http://test",
    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/redact/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/redact",
    "roleDefinitionName": "Contributor",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/redact",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
  }
]
```

...**or assigning a system-assigned managed identity**...

- using `az functionapp identity assign -g MyResourceGroup -n MyUniqueApp`)...

There is often a `--scope` option. I can't find a list of these scopes and descriptions anywhere.

Looking for something like `az account list-locations --query [].displayName` but substitute `[].scopes` instead.

**Does anyone know where these can be found?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "az ad sp" command '--scopes' parameter refers to the target resource(with Subscription, Resource Group details) to which you want to attach the Service Principle.

Ex: *az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "test" --role contributor 
    --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}*

So listing of scopes mean, you need to list resources within subscriptions you have access to. Below command might help:

**az resource list** *--subscription* *--resource-group*

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list) azure cli page.

Comment: Right. So what are all the options for `--scopes`? Where are the options described? The link you send does not contain the string "scope". Its defined as:
`Space-separated list of scopes the service principal's role assignment applies to. Defaults to the root of the current subscription.`

Comment: Found a partial list in the docs here under the `--scope` flag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-definition-list. The syntax I want to understand are things like `.../myGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM`. How would I know to add "providers" the "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" if I wanted to assign a resource-level scope? Also, what permissions does a top level "subscription" scope provide an identity?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @megh-6789. To expand on your answer, after running `az resource list --subscription $sub_id`, I can see the `id` for the resource matches the `--scopes` syntax I was looking for.

**Example:**

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/redact/resourceGroups/redact/providers/Microsoft.Maps/accounts/redact",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": "global",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "redact",
    "plan": null,
    "properties": null,
    "resourceGroup": "redact",
    "sku": {
      "capacity": null,
      "family": null,
      "model": null,
      "name": "s1",
      "size": null,
      "tier": "Standard"
    },
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Maps/accounts"
  }
```

It looks like its possible to set `scope` to a subscription, resource group or resource-level.